# The shortest road with 2 ways of transport

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

I have to write a programme that counts the shortest way from city A to B considering 2 ways of transport and maxium number of changing them. So for example we have input like this :

```
A B 8 6 : 
B C 3 1 : 
C D 7 14
```

where A B C D are cities and numbers are 'costs' between them: first for car ,second for train. User writes that he wants to use maximum one change of transport. So in this example its 14

```
(A->B(train) 
B->C(train)
C->D(car)
```

and without any changes its 18-car only. Ofcourse i represent it as a directed graph. Also i tried to make 2 vertices for each city so that "train stations" are connected only with "train stations" and "car stops" only with "car stops" + make edges between them indicating cost of transition(car->train , train->car )- with bigger cost, changing wont be so good ( and with cost == 0 dijkstra will use it as many times as its needed to make road shorter ). However i don't know what cost of changing transport ( and how to count it ) i should use to get shortest way with lower or the same number of transition written by user. Please help me.

Comment: My bet is that no one here will write any code for you, since: 1. you did not show any attempt, 2. it's probably a bit big, 3. looks like a homework. I suggest you to look a multigraphs, and ask specific question for specific problems in your attempts to implement a specific algorithm. PS. There is no question.

Comment: Well i don't want code. And i described what i want to do ( 1 city = 2 vertices - edge between them with cost of changing transport ). If that cost is bigger , there are less transitions and if its 0 dijkstra will make as many changes of transport as its needed to make the shortest road. Is it good idea ? And also it isn't finished because i don't know what value i should use for cost of change and how to count it, anyone has idea ?

Comment: Yeah i've read that topic, however i don't understand that idea so well thats why i tried to make something different. The question is , if my idea is correct and how to finish it?